Change segmentaion rule in spacy library
I am trying to change (not to add to the pipeline)  the segmentation rule used by Spacy NLP library.
Used version of spacy:
spacy=3.7.2 

import:
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

sentence I want to segment
myString = "This is a sentrance. This is another. \n\n This is \n third one."

The rule that I want to use (segment depending on new line "only")
from spacy.pipeline import Sentencizer
def split_on_newlines(doc):
    start= 0
    seen_newline = False
    for word in doc:
        if seen_newline:
            yield doc[start:word.i]
            start=word.i
            seen_newline = False
        elif word.text.startwith('\n'):
            seen_newline= True
    yield doc[start:]

in previous versions there was SentenceSegmenter model which it was replaced by Sentencizer model
with SentendSegmenter it was straightforward to change the rule:
sbd = SentenceSegmenter(nlp.vocab, strategy=split_on_newlines)
nlp.add_pipe(sbd)

but now with Sentencizer I do not know the exact steps:
@Language.component("split_on_newlines")
def split_on_newlines(doc):
    start= 0
    seen_newline = False
    for word in doc:
        if seen_newline:
            yield doc[start:word.i]
            start=word.i
            seen_newline = False
        elif word.text.startwith('\n'):
            seen_newline= True
    yield doc[start:]

sbd = Sentencizer('split_on_newlines', overwrite= True)

is this correct ? if yes then what is next ?
please note there is question that is similar to this, but this was how to add a new rule not to change the default strategy
